# NodeJS Aws sdk, can't unset credentials

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I have a NodeJS application that runs on an EC2 instance that serves API to my customers. EC2 instance have a Instance Role that grants the minimum permissions for the application to access services it needs ( i need sqs, s3 Read and write, and ses ).
 One particular endpoint in my api is for creating a signed url, in order to be able to access s3 files, and to create the signed url i use an IAM user with only s3 read access to that Bucket.

My issue is that, whenever that endpoint is called the AWS credentials are set using

```
const awsConfig = {
    region,
    accessKeyId: ${keyofreadonlyuser},
    secretAccessKey: ${secretofreadonlyuser},
};
AWS.config.update(awsConfig);
```

This way, all subsequent calls to aws sdk will use that credentials resulting in a Access Denied error.
I've tried to set `accessKeyId: null, secretAccessKey:null` and than call AWS.config.update, but the credentials are not cleared. 
What is the best way to handle situations like that ?

Comment: Why doesn't your instance role also have access to S3?

Comment: It have, but it's configured as read/write, and i'd prefere to use a read only user for signing

Comment: Well if your instance already has access, locking down the user within the application which already has access to read/write means nothing from a security perspective.

Comment: Don't update the AWS config. Simply create a new, transient boto3 session specifically for the 2nd use case, passing in the IAM user credentials to the [session](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html) constructor.

Comment: That's what i end up with, @jarmod thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that instead of updating the default config, you instead use two boto3 sessions objects:

1. the default, implicitly-created session, that's associated with the assumed IAM role
2. an explicitly-created session, that's associated with the IAM user credentials

Specifically for the 2nd use case, pass the IAM user credentials to the [session](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html) constructor.